# Why C compiler says *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated

Tags: c

**What is problem with my code, that it shows "stack smashing detected"
Problem Statement:**
*Given an array, we have to find the smallest element in the array.*

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int arr[20],i,j,c,x,num;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    for(x=0;x<num;x++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[x]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(arr)-1;i++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
            c=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1]=c;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",*(arr+0));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to trace through the logic of the code. Hint: what do you expect to be the result of `sizeof(arr)`? What *is* the result? Do you understand why?

Comment: What if `num` > 20?

Comment: Always check user input. Always.

Comment: I'm asking for less than 20. But still same result.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes the exact input required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh, and it is not the _compiler_ but your _program_ that emits that message.

Answer (score 0):

If the user-provided value `num` is greater than 20, your code will write to memory off the end of the array `arr`. This is undefined behaviour, and likely to cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

(1) `int arr[20]` can only hold twenty values, but you let the user put in any number.

(2) `sizeof(arr)` gives you the size in bytes, not the number of elements.

The compiler is able to detect one or both of these problems, and give you an error message telling you.

Comment: I'm aware of first one, but the second point cleared my doubt. Thankyou...